# Java spring-rest/ Jersey how secure rest route with filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jersey

I use the following in the `pom.xml` which is actually securing the **root** **route**,
I see the authentication process starting in the browser for few seconds

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Now I've specific routes that I need to secure when user chooses them...

```
@Path("/run")
public class Service {


...

@GET
@Path("connect/{param}")
public Response connectToHost(@PathParam("param") String host) {
```

How I should do it ? via configuration on the pom as above or via code for each route ?

Comment: I would prefer going with the specific codes for `DummyService`. This would help to keep the `pom.xml` clean and also code can be maintained properly at later stage.

Comment: @Henry - No this is the only thing that I've added

Comment: @CodeHunter - can you please provide example how it should be done ?

Comment: @Henry - Yes I use Jersey  rest framework

Comment: Sorry for delay. You can have a look at this tutorial for more details:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkKcdK1u95s&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn

It is really a concise tutorial and you'll get more details here.

Comment: are you sure the filter mapping is in the pom.xml? Shouln't it be in web.xml? Also, this filter provides CSRF protection for all URLs. Do you want to keep CSRF protection for only some URLs?

Comment: If I may have understood it correctly, are u talking about after authentication you want to authorize the user for specific REST API call?

Comment: I think you mean in the `web.xml` not the `pom.xml` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some confusing points in your questions, but I'll try to cover whatever I can.

**ONE. filter settings** - As per your question you made filter settings in `pom.xml`. But actually filter settings are always made in `web.xml` file. If you have mistakenly named pom.xml then ignore but if not then move the filter settings to web.xml.

**TWO.** In your question tags you have mentioned that your query is related to spring-boot, spring-security. But the code sample that you have attached suggests you are perhaps using jersey for creating rest apis and not using spring, spring-security. You are actually trying to use csrf protection at lower level at tomcat server level. Thats fine.

**THREE.** CSRF protection can be leveraged with spring security as well as tomcat apis.

**FOUR.** If you want to understand how spring security provides csrf protection to rest endpoints you will have to provide following configuration in your code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

This will provide csrf protection to all POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE requests to your application. Refer - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html for more details.

**FIVE.** Now for your actual question of how to provide csrf protection to multiple routes to your **jersey** based rest endpoints... You can provide multiple url patterns like following.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/run</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/path1</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/path2</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Refer - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter_for_REST_APIs for more details on `RestCsrfPreventionFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

**

### The best way to secure rest full web service by using spring security if you are not using any other specification.

**
**1**. ***Using Spring way,you need to declare 
    Filter Mapping*** ->

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter- 
class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**2. Then you have to create a spring-security.xml . You can declare your 
    method which you want to prevent to access.So you can ask for some 
    authorization checked before accessing that methods.**

```
          <beans:bean  id="cacheManager" 
        class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
             <beans:property name="caches">
                 <beans:set>
                     <beans:bean  
     class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                         <beans:property name="name" value="ltPrevileges"/>
                     </beans:bean >
                     <beans:bean  
    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                         <beans:property name="name" value="dashboard"/>
                     </beans:bean >
                 </beans:set>
             </beans:property>
         </beans:bean> 

        <beans:bean id="cacheManager" 
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" >
           <beans:property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
         <beans:bean id="ehcache" 
             class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
              <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"></beans:property>
              <beans:property name="shared" value="true"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
            entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" 
            pattern="/sheel/practice/getBatchDetails"
            create-session="stateless">
            <security:csrf disabled="true" />
            <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
                ref="authorizationGlobalFilterBean" />
        </security:http>
        </beans:bean>
        <!-- Login auth ends here -->
        <!-- PreAuth starts here -->
        <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
            entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" pattern="/framework/**"
            create-session="stateless">
            <security:csrf disabled="true" />
            <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
                ref="siteminderFilter" />
        </security:http>
            <beans:bean id="authorizationGlobalFilterBean"
            class="com.xplanr.framework.security.AuthorizationGlobalFilter">
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="siteminderFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeader    AuthenticationFilter">
            <beans:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="sessionId" />
            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" 
    ref="authenticationManager" />
        </beans:bean>
        <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider
                ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
        </security:authentication-manager>
     <beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider"        
     class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
                    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
                     class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" 
                           ref="customUserDetailsService" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
         <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
            class="com.practice.framework.security.CustomUserDetailsService"> 
       </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint"      
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
        </beans:bean>
       <!--PreAuth ends here -->
        </beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all Filters should be added to **web.xml** file. It should **not be added to pom.xml** file. pom.xml is only the manifest for building your project.

Since it is best to secure only certain urls for your intended CSRF Prevention filter, use specific urls in filter mapping.

Example is provided for the mentioned `/run` path.

```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/run</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Please refer [this oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015950) to understand the usage of web.xml elements.

To understand further regarding filtering requests and responses, refer [this oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html).

Refer [this practical tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/web-filter-example.html) on understand hoe to configure the filters in both xml and annotation methods. Note that you do not have to do the configurations in both ways. It can be done in either xml based or annotation based way as you're comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

      private AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = {
          new AntPathRequestMatcher("/run/connect/**")
      };

      @Override
      public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        for (AntPathRequestMatcher rm : requestMatchers) {
          // If request matches specified urls, apply csfr
          if (rm.matches(request)) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
      }

    }; 
    http
      // Enable csrf only on some request matches
      .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
      //Other configurations
  }
}
```